# How do I navigate to a new page from within a view, with React?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, view, react-router

I have a React Single Page App that has a static top bar in which I do not want to put any navigation. I want to change the view/page from a link that is inside the main view itself. I've had no luck so far.

Basically due to the fact that I wrote this app while learning React, means that I now realize my whole state and all functions are basically in the wrong place, they're in one page, and now that I am upgrading my Single Page App to have more views, I will have to share state between pages and thus lift it up to a new App that is the parent to both. All functions, logic and code is too ingrained in this one page so I'll have to improvise.

In the structure, the Home.jsx page contains **all the app's State**, and honestly I can not fathom even rewriting that right now. This is my first project and I really just need a win or I'll burn out. It's all very entrenched. So basically I want the Home.jsx page to remain the main page with all the State in it, because it works very well this way, and just pass functions and other state as props to Overview.jsx so it knows what's up.

```
                                       App View
                                        |    |
                                      |        |
                                Home.jsx     Overview.jsx
                              (main page)    (second page)
                                  |                 |
                                 |                    |
                       This page should            This one should have a 
                                                           link
                      have a NavLink or            that goes back to
                     something else                    Home.jsx
                  which triggers the App view
                  to load Overview.jsx
                     ---and this is what I can't 
                     seem to do.
```

I've tried React Router, but nowhere in the documentation or even online have I found an answer to how to link from one view/page to another from WITHIN the first page, and then to go back by clicking something WITHIN the now open second view.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=110dW3l5GQY

Answer (score 0):

you can use **link** or **a tag** to navigate from one to another from view. Examples

```
<link to='path' />
<a href='path'
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `<Router>` to tell React what to render based on the path and then you can use `<Link>` in the different components. See [React Router's basic routing example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start/example-basic-routing) for more details.

Inside App.js:

```js
<Router>
  <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
  <Route path="/overview" component={Overview}
</Router>
```

Inside Overview.js:

```js
<Link to="/">Home</Link>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, as I am already working in my main app file. My main file is already Home.jsx, so from that file all the magic has to happen. It's not a component, it's the file from within everything already happens. That is my main problem!

Comment: Can you post your code? I'm not understanding how the two pages are related.

Comment: It's a hell of a lot of code, but basically my index.jsx is empty and all my state and important stuff is in Home.jsx, a page. But I cannot tell Home.jsx to render itself within Home.jsx, and then if I click somewhere that Home.jsx will be replaced with Page2.jsx, because it can't render above itself. I thought about it for a long time and I think I just gotta bite the bullet, make a pot of coffee, put on some music and rewrite this thing the whole night.

Comment: Alternatively you could add some conditional rendering that would replace the Home component with the Overview component using state to say which component to show. 

Personally, I find if I rewrite code I tend to write better code the second time, even if it's time consuming. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah @displacedtexan I thought about that, too, but figured this way I'll get some Router experience in there, will look good on the Portfolio. Thanks for the help and all the best!